# C++ What is this piece of code doing?

Tags: c++

Im not exactly sure what argv[1][i] means or argv[1][i-1]. I'm very new to C++ and need some help with these functions. Like what does char arg = arv[1][i] do to the array?

```
int i = 0, j = 0, num1 = 0, num2 = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 3)
    {
        while (argv[1][i] != '\0')
        {
            char arg = argv[1][i];
            if (!isdigit(arg) && arg != '.' && arg != ',' &&
                arg != 'e' && arg != 'E' && arg != '+' && arg != '-')
            {
                cout << "X\n";
                return 0;
            }
            if (arg == '.')
            {
                if (!isdigit(argv[1][i-1]))
                {
                    cout << "X\n";
                    return 0;
                }
```

Comment: It does nothing to the array. Have you so much as read page 1 of a C textbook? (Never mind C++)

Answer (score 1):

`argv[1][i]` is the `i`th character of `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `argv` is a `char**`, meaning that it is an array of `char*` strings. So, `argv[1]` is a `char*`, so `argv[1][i]` is the `i`'th character in the `char[1]` string. This code is simply searching through the individual characters in the string.

Comment: No, the OP does not remember that `argv` is  `char **` because the OP doesn't yet even understand what an array is, much less what `char **` is.